# HTTPS request served by Apache2 slower than via Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, go, https, webserver, reverse-proxy

**My situation:**
A website is hosted using a default apache2 installation on an ubuntu server.
Served on port 443 using HTTPS and a self-signed certificate (for developping).

Now I have a simple service written in golang that listens at port 8080 and acts as a Reverse Proxy to take https requests, forward them to apache locally and return the response back to the client. This webservice doesn't cache any files and only forwards requests.
Code: https://play.golang.org/p/tnfKVWyLuZQ

**My "problem":**
Calling apache directly, i.e. `https://foo.com/bar/` is remarkably slower (200-400ms) than calling the website through my reverse proxy, i.e. `https://foo.com:8080/bar/`

Why is it slower to call apache2 directly? I expected to have overhead using a reverse proxy, not a speedup. -> Comparison for example page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq2g5.png

---

**UPDATE**: Sketch to show the current setup:
[Current Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yto4h.png)

**Regarding the encoding**: The Encoding is consistent in both situations: Encoding header and Content-Length is in both cases (Situation 1 vs 2) the same, the client also receives the file size. Not sure why in the HAR Viewer it only displays the uncompressed size in the second case. If checking in Chrome I can see the compressed size in both case.

**Update #2**: I came to the conclusion that the golang implementation handles multiple requests from the same client in a short time more efficiently than apache2 in it's default configuration. Sicne I only test with few clients I can't say how well it scales - I imagine the webservice will fall behind when under load.
I see this as closed, thanks all for the help.

Comment: Not quite enough information to know for sure, but I'm betting your reverse proxy is maintaining a persistent connection to the apache2 server, preventing `tcp` and `ssl` handshake overhead with each request.

Comment: Good idea. But wouldn't the reverse proxy have the same issue (as it handles the same requests as the webserver would)?  It's hard to believe for me that golang's implementation is more efficient than apache. Any suggestions where/how I could gather more info? Thanks!

Comment: My comment is assuming the go proxy is running on localhost, and that apache2 is some remote server. If that is true, then the first request after starting the proxy may be the same speed, but subsequent requests would utilize the proxy's persisted connection, and avoid some overhead. The connection overhead from the browser to the proxy is negligible, if it's running on localhost, as I've presumed.

Comment: I just noticed that the request sizes are significantly smaller on the apache requests. Apache is likely doing gzip compression of your resources by default, and that could also add to overhead. Check the `http` headers between the proxy and apache, and see what the contents of `accept-encoding` header are.

Comment: Thanks the idea, I looked into the encoding and it is consistent over both cases (see updated answer). The webservice that acts as the reverse proxy sits on the server itself. I added an image to elaborate.

Comment: The diagram is very helpful. My initial assumptions were wrong. My best guess at this point is that the proxy is doing a better job allowing the browser to do pipelining. You're doing a _lot_ of `GET` requests, and if apache is requiring a new `TCP` connection for each, and the proxy is not, that would explain the overhead.

Comment: I did more testing and I come to think, as you said, the webservice written in go handles this case more efficient than apache (in it's default configuration). Most likely it won't scale as well but I'm only testing on few clients so I can't judge that.
Thanks for the help on this!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see. There are two possible reasons.

1. The apache reverse proxy handled some cache contain static file like images, css or javascript.
2. When you browse a https url. A process named "ssl certificate uninstall" will happen, and it can cause huge server load. So if the web application and the ssl certificate are deployed on the same server, the load may cause high-latency. Generally, we use a special device named load-balancer to uninstall ssl certificate, Just like a reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - The proxy isn't doing any caching itself, only forwarding (see code snipped).
While ssl might be a bottleneck it should be consistent over both cases right? Since I connect to apache and to the webservice using https in both cases.